# I want to use custom language translation in application other than system language, how to do that?

Tags: android, translation

In my android application, I want to implement a function - it has strings whose translation can be changed with system language, as well as strings whose translation should not be changed with the system language and instead should change as the user wants.

Example:

```
  can you say "中文", please try to say "你好"
```

In the above sentence, the strings outside quotes should change with the system language, but those inside quotes should change as the user wants or selects.

How do I implement this function in android?

---

but I don't want to add a DB to my application. How can I achieve this with arrays, how to save the translation strings in arrays, and get and merge strings?

if the system language is English, how can I get Chinese strings from saved arrays?

And I also find another away achieving this target, is like below code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();

/** 
 *update the desired locale, if I want to get chinese string, 
 *change configuration to Chinese locale.
**/
res.getConfiguration().locale = Locale.getDefault(); 
res.updateCXonfiguration(config, dm);
String text = res.getString(R.string.merges_tring)

//when I get the string I want, 
//then restore the configraion locale to previous/current locale.
 ...code...

//below code, to merge the get string
 ...code...
```

how do you think this way? Will it get any defects to the system language?

Answer (score 2):

Use strings like those in separate resource files per language. The system will select the string by the system language.

In a file *res/values/strings.xml*

```
<string name="example">can you say "$1%s", please try to say "$2%s"</string>
```

In a file *res/values-de/string.xml*

```
<string name="example">Können Sie "$1%s" sagen, bitte versuchen Sie "$2%s" zu sagen.</string>
```

Now for the other parts:

In your code, get the parts by the language selected by the user. There is no defined way for that, an easy method could be to have them in arrays or in a database. I use a hypotetical method `getMyString` here, which would take the user selected language and a key to inidicate which string you'd want.

```
String s1 = getMyString(userSelectedLanguage, stringKey1);  // e.g. 中文
String s2 = getMyString(userSelectedLanguage, stringKey2);  // e.g. 你好
```

Now use the getString() method provided by Activity class to merge the strings.

```
String msg = getString(R.string.example, s1, s2);
```

This will result in either of the following, depending on the system language:

`can you say "中文", please try to say "你好"` or
`Können Sie "中文" sagen, bitte versuchen Sie "你好" zu sagen.`.

Comment: thank your good advice, I tried that, it can achive what I want

Comment: thank you, Ridcully. I tried you advice these days. It's good advices.